# Check to see if a message is in a POSIX message queue w/o removing it from the queue?

Tags: posix, message-queue

POSIX provides a way to read a message queue using its mq_receive function. This function also removes it from the queue.  I need to find a way to check to see if a message is in the queue without removing it.

Answer (score 0):

From the Linux mq_overview(7) man page:

> #### Polling message queue descriptors
>
> On Linux, a message queue descriptor  is  actually  a  file  descriptor,  and  can  be  monitored  using
>        **select**(2), **poll**(2), or **epoll**(7).  This is not portable.

Comment: Thanks.

Right I have "faked" it in order to get it to work by immediatedly doing a mq_send with a high priority message after using a mq_recieve in a check msg queue fashion.

Answer (score 0):

See `mq_getattr(3)`.  One of the attributes is `mq_curmsgs`.  It's nice to actually get a queue depth, in addition to the boolean indication you'll get from `epoll()`.

From the Linux manpage:

```
       struct mq_attr {
           long mq_flags;       /* Flags: 0 or O_NONBLOCK */
           long mq_maxmsg;      /* Max. # of messages on queue */
           long mq_msgsize;     /* Max. message size (bytes) */
           long mq_curmsgs;     /* # of messages currently in queue */
       };
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to add a mq_attr data structure when openning a message queue, then get attributes with mq_getattr function

int mq_getattr(mqd_t mqdes, struct mq_attr *attr);

lastly, look at its mq_curmsgs member